# How to serve an index.html in react js in http2

Tags: express, http2

How to serve an index.html in react JS in http2....
like below express code

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../build`));

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
res.status(200).sendFile(`${__dirname}/../build/index.html`);
  });
 console.log('server is running')


const port = 2002;

app.listen(port, () => console.info(`app listening to port ${port} `));
```

Comment: Look [this](https://webapplog.com/http2-node/) tutorial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js server and HTTP/2 (2.0) with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639995/node-js-server-and-http-2-2-0-with-express-js)