# Move from HTTP1 to HTTP2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have express server build on HTTP1 protocol.

How I can move my express server built on HTTP1 to the HTTP2 protocol? Is there native support in Express?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js server and HTTP/2 (2.0) with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639995/node-js-server-and-http-2-2-0-with-express-js)

Comment: I'm trying to find native way using express